# Error at line 5/30: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

```
SELECT FLIGHT.FLIGHTID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMER.NAME, CONCAT(CUSTOMER.EMAIL, CUSTOMER.PHONE)
From location WHERE LOCATION.AIRPORTCODE = 'NED'
ORDER BY ROUTE.ROUTEID,
CASE
WHEN ROUTE.ARRIVEAIRPORTCODE THEN FLIGHTID, CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERNAME, EMAIL
WHEN ROUTE.DEPARTAIRPORTCODE = 'NED' THEN FLIGHTID, CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERNAME, PHONE
END;
```

Comment: [`order_by_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6): `ORDER [ SIBLINGS ] BY { expr | position | c_alias }`. This is **not an expression**: `... THEN FLIGHTID, CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERNAME, EMAIL`

Answer (score 0):

Two major issues:

- query uses data from 3 tables, while your `FROM` clause has only one table. You're missing (outer) joins to (at least) two another tables
- `ORDER BY` clause is wrong; you don't sort by all these columns *conditionally*; it is just the last one that depends on the value of `DEPARTAIRPORTCODE`

---

```
SELECT FLIGHT.FLIGHTID, 
       CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, 
       CUSTOMER.NAME, 
       CONCAT(CUSTOMER.EMAIL, CUSTOMER.PHONE)
From location join flight on ...                  --> missing (outer?) joins
              join customer on ...                -->
WHERE LOCATION.AIRPORTCODE = 'NED'
ORDER BY ROUTE.ROUTEID,
         FLIGHTID, 
         CUSTOMERID, 
         CUSTOMERNAME, 
         -- this is how CASE expression should look like 
         CASE WHEN ROUTE.DEPARTAIRPORTCODE = 'NED' THEN PHONE
              ELSE EMAIL
         CASE;
```